# Confusing regarding a template sustitution example

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, sfinae

I am confused about this code from "The C++ programming language 4th, 28.4.4"

```
template<typename T>
struct get_f_result {
private:
    template<typename X>
    static auto check(X const& x) −> decltype(f(x)); // can call f(x)
    static substitution_failure check(...); // cannot call f(x)
public:
    using type = decltype(check(std::declval<T>()));
};
```

The part that I am specifically confused about is this line here:

```
static substitution_failure check(...); // cannot call f(x)
```

But I remember `...` could not accept non pod type? So how could this work?

Comment: `(...)` can accept any type. If `decltype(f(x))` is valid then first `check(const X&)` is selected, otherwise the second `check(...)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`...` can take any types; passing a non-POD type may not be supported, but is syntactically valid.

In this case, the function call isn't evaluated (since it's only used in an unevaluated context, as the operand of `decltype`), so there's no undefined behaviour, just a compile-time attempt to match the function call with a suitable overload.